# How to submit unchecked checkboxes to controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, checkbox

Ok first I have a "settings" table on my database in which I have the fields "name" and "value" its a configuration kind of table where the value could be anything from string to boolean values etc.

Now on my blade, I have a form with various inputs "texts" "selects" "checkboxes" etc. When submitting the form on the controller I run a `foreach` where for each attribute of the `$request` I store its key as the name and its value as its value on the database.

```
$agency_id = Auth::user()->agency->id;
$settings = AgencySettings::whereAgencyId($agency_id)->get();
foreach ($request->except('_token') as $key => $value)
{
    $setting = $settings->where('name','=',$key)->first();
    if (boolval($setting))
    {
        $setting->value = $value;
        $setting->update();
    }else{
        $setting = new AgencySettings;
        $setting->agency_id = $agency_id;
        $setting->name = $key;
        $setting->value = $value;
        $setting->save();
    }
}
```

All works well except the unchecked checkboxes which are not inside the `$request`.
I know I can handle them like so `$request->has('name_of_checkbox')` but because of the dynamic nature of the table on the database, I don't want to have hardcoded on my Controller the name of a specific setting.

My goal is that the code on my Controller will be the same regardless the number of different settings I will use on my frontend (maybe in the future there will be a need to add more).

So my question, is there a way to handle those checkboxes serverside without having to refer to them specifically, or a way to always return the value of the checkboxes to the server despite its state?

My first thought is to go with javascript and hidden inputs, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: If you want to use the value of the checkbox in every request, you'll have to use javascript for your post request. When a checkbox it is not included in the standard post request.

Comment: You mean using an ajax request?

Comment: Yes, or you can set a hidden input thats set to 'on' or 'off' or whatever you like and have that value represent the checkbox value.

Comment: Yes that was my approach also, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a hidden field with the same name before every checkbox you want to receive, like :

```
<input type="hidden"   name="checkbox-1" value="0" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" value="1" /> My checbox 1
```

That will send the hidden field with the 0 value when the field is unchecked and send the proper truthy value when it's checked.

**NOTE:** Just make sure you're adding the hidden field first so you'll receive just the checked one when the field is checked.

Comment: So right, and no javascript code, smart answer, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Also even without the hidden input should work I think just by setting the zero default value!
```<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" value="0" />```

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: How solid this solution is? I.e. What prevent browsers from sending fields in different order nuking this trick?

Comment: You may need to ask the opposite, what will make the browsers shaking the order of my fields? (Since they never do).

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to simply check if value for "checkbox-1" is set in post array.
So you will set default to 0 on your controller side and check if value exists instead of checking if it is 0 or 1.

(M.)

Comment: _My goal is that the code on my Controller will be the same regardless the number of different settings I will use on my frontend_ Read the question again carefully.

Comment: Or, if are array of checkboxes, you can use a specific value for each configuration, like "Can save" = 1, "Can load" = 2, then you get in controller by request and use by value (considering unique). Depends on which responsibility you prefer, have predefined values ​​(constants), or "duplicate" inputs.

Comment: So, if you will take proposed approach the key is in transferring configuration to your Viewer. You can still check if value exists in Controller and maintain configuration flexibility by generating "name" values from your configuration.